# Why is my corporate Internet speed low over VPN?

Tags: vpn, internet

I suspect that my ISP is throttling speed when I am on VPN. I get faster speed when I am not on VPN, but it drops when I connect to VPN. I am talking about corporate VPN here, so I am ruling out the possibility that my corporate VPN has slower speed.

I know that VPN traffic uses encrypted tunnel end to end and ISP won't be able to find out where I am browsing from and what I am browsing. But would the ISP know when I am using VPN and when I am not?

Speed difference is significant, on VPN I get around 2 mbps and without VPN I get around 18 mbps

Comment: why would you rule out your corporate VPN being slower?  Many companies limit VPN speed.

Answer (score 1):

It's called overhead, and yes, even on your corporate VPN that means your speed over VPN will be slower, often FAR slower, than without it.

Basically, it takes processing power to perform the encryption and decryption necessary for VPN communication. There is also extra data beyond just the basic data being sent back and forth over your regular internet connection, when you are using VPN. Finally, there is the distance and number of hops the network traffic must travel over a VPN versus over your internet.

Another factor is the network components of the corporate network you are connecting to and through. Each of these have there own limits and can add their own overhead, and then consider you are sharing these with any other coworkers who are also working over VPN, and the network "pie" gets cut into smaller and smaller pieces.

All this means that it is entirely and completely normal, and expected even, for your internet speed over VPN to be a relatively small fraction of your internet speed not over VPN, and this slow down is no indication on its own of throttling by your ISP.

Comment: I am talking about significant difference in speed here, on VPN it is around 2 mbps and without VPN it is around 18 mbps.

Comment: That's slow internet, to begin with, and yes, that is still within the realm of the possible-to-normal.